# Background downloading of a file

Tags: java, download, background

I am new. I have a program where I click a button and the download of a movie begins, but when it download it, I can't do anything, so the program is going to shut down or is still frozen (The File i want to download is 2GB. My download code looks like this:

So I want that I can do something in my program and it would be so great if anybody knows how I can add a progress bar, so I can see how the download is going.

```
if (!"Anschauen".equals(down.getText())) {
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("gedown.txt", true)))) {
        bw.write(titles.getText());
        bw.newLine();

        String fileName = (titles.getText()+".mp4"); //The file that will be saved on your computer
        URL link = new URL("http://s180.zerocdn.to/dl/63974fae7073944b11a7cf3e72e36cec/58b0d089/mm59cc5df499f1c21806495fea50072438.mp4"); //The file that you want to download

        switch (titles.getText()) {
            case "doesnotmatter":
                link = new URL("doesnotmatter");
                break;
            case "doesnotmatter":
                link = new URL("doesnotmatter");
                break;
            case "doesnotmatter":
                link = new URL("doesnotmatter");
                break;
            case "doesnotmatter":
                link = new URL("doesnotmatter");
                break;
            case "doesnotmatter":
                link = new URL("doesnotmatter");
                break;
            case "doesnotmatter":
                link = new URL("doesnotmatter");
                break;
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream out;
        try (InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(link.openStream())) {
            out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int n = 0;
            while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
            {
                out.write(buf, 0, n);
            }
            out.close();
        }
        byte[] response = out.toByteArray();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        fos.write(response);
        fos.close();
    }
}
else {
    System.out.println("Noch nicht fertig");
}
```

Comment: You probably should learn the concept of Threads (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Thread ([Official Info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html))

```
public void run() {
    //This will be called when the thread starts.
    //Put the download code right here.
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    //The class must implement Runnable. 
    Thread thread = new Thread(this, "Thread's name eg. Download  Thread");
    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: Put all the download code in a separate class and run it as a thread. Then, use a get method to return the progress.